# Find all the natural numbers between $1 \leq a \leq 1000$ which fulfill $a^{11764} \equiv a^4\pmod{25725}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all the natural numbers between $1 \leq a \leq 1000$ which fulfill $a^{11764} \equiv a^4\pmod{25725}$.

What I have tried so far was reducing $a$ and factoring the modulus to a smaller number related to $5$.

Comment: Note: $25725 = 3 * 5^2 * 7^3$. By the Chinese Remainder theorem, the result will hold if and only if $a^{11764} \equiv a^4$ holds modulo $3$, modulo $5^2$, and modulo $7^3$.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Fermat-Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)? Do you see how this result is useful here?

Comment: You can begin by putting $ b=a^4$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann This was the clue i was looking for, it solves my question. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: The simple answer is: all of them.

Comment: Actually, $a^{11763} \equiv a^3\pmod{25725}$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length

Comment: Special case of the Theorem in the linked dupe. Here $\,11760 = \phi(25725)\ \ $